# DCEF3 cache - on user base

Tags: delphi, caching, chromium-embedded

I'm using Chromium Embedded (DCEF3) in a Delphi application; I have a question about the Chromium Embedded cache. 
I have it as a subdirectory of program folder, but I should want to differentiate cache for different users (in other words, each user having cache folder in user's folder) 
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You specify the location of the cache by assigning a value to `CefCache`. So, assign a value that is somewhere under the current user's profile.